# Eagle PCB : Is there a pcb equivalent to the schematic net label that I can put on my silk?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

As we know the schematic editor has the ability to apply labels (of two styles) to nets that automatically update when the net name is changed.

I'm wondering if the pcb editor has an equivalent that will let me add silk text (on tPlace for example) that references the name of a net.

I know you can use codes like >NAME and >VALUE to reference the attributes of a component in a library symbol.  It seems like you can add arbitrary attributes and reference them in your footprint (see [here](https://macrofab.com/blog/how-to-use-part-attribute-eagle/)) but I don't see a way to access the name of the net.

I guess this can be done with a ULP but I'd prefer not to resort to that.

Comment: This seems like an odd request, why would you want the signal name on your PCB? You'd have to place the label every so often because you'd be following it from one side of the signal to the other.

Comment: @RonBeyer the only way I could see this being useful is if you had a label in a part's footprint tied to the net of a specific pin

Comment: I have about 40 pins on a few connectors to individually re-label.  They already have text labels with the old names, the new labels are already on the nets and complex enough to type that this is going to take a while by hand.

Comment: @TomKeddie the nice thing about Eagle files is that they are just XML stored in plain text, so you could use Notepad++ or something to edit the file directly to fix the existing labels. Much faster than editing each one in Eagle. I do this all the time.

Comment: https://www.element14.com/community/thread/54385/l/display-netname-on-silkscreen?displayFullThread=true

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, no there is no way of achieving this automatically.

It would probably be possible to do with a ULP, or alternatively you could simply use the text tool and manually entering the name of the net.